# Specflow AfterScenario

Tags: c#, specflow

Using Specflow attributes

I am trying to get a piece of code to run at the very end, so when all tests are finished.

All tests are set to run in parallel

There might be multiple features and scenarios running and I need this to only run once and at the very end when everything is finished, not after each feature because placed in there it will run multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Use the AfterTestRun hook.

For more specification about the hooks:
https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Hooks

Comment: If I actually read the description on that link rather than assuming the name means before each (individual) test I wouldn't have had to post this question....duhhh Cheers for your help